# Can't add textblock to Stackpanel Children

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock

I have the codes above which create a popup with a textblock, a progress bar and a button programmatically then show. Progress bar and button were ok but the textblock I added to stackpanel.children didnt show up. Anyone have idea for this problem ? Thanks so much.

```
                var tbInfo = new TextBlock {Text = "Checking... ", TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap, Visibility = Visibility.Visible};
            var mainPanel = new StackPanel {Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)};
            var popupBtnCancle = new Button {Content = "Cancel", Margin = new Thickness(3)};
            popupBtnCancle.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(popupBtnCancle_Click);
            var pbLoading = new ProgressBar
            {
                IsIndeterminate = true,
                IsEnabled = true,
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
            };


            mainPanel.Children.Add(tbInfo);
            mainPanel.Children.Add(pbLoading);
            mainPanel.Children.Add(popupBtnCancle);
            border.Child = mainPanel;
            _loading.Child = border;
            _loading.VerticalOffset = 0;
            _loading.HorizontalOffset = 0;
            _loading.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: I had a similar issue just yesterday, when I defined a custom  `ContentControl` to be displayed in a `Popup`. It turned out that the Background defaultet to black for some reason. Setting it to white made black letters visible :)

Comment: holy cow, it's true, i set foreground to white and it shows up :) Answer it, i will mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the default background for `Popup`s is black. Your text is rendered in black letters, though.
Black cats at night are hard to spot :)

Set one of the two values to something else and you'll see that your `TextBlock` is indeed there.